# What is the best way to use a Custom .net control from a legacy C++ app?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, legacy-code

I maintain a legacy application (unmanaged C++) and I need a new control (Basic Form). I would like to build this control in C# for simplicity but use it from my legacy app. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of control?  What kind of application?

Comment: Also, since it's a 'legacy' application, I'm going to assume that it's unmanaged C++, but specifying if it's managed or unmanaged c++ would help too.

Comment: Legacy application is unmanaged C++. The control will just be a Windows Form.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might want to make a COM control in C#, register it and use it from within your C++ application. I can't see any other way of using a .NET control in C++ - however, I haven't tried that.

Comment: This was my first thoughts as well, and I was able to get it work. Basically by createing an interface with the method:

        public IntPtr GetHandle()
        {
            return this.Handle;
        }

I was able to get a handle to my component and add do any modifications required in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could build the c++ into a dll and use it, but there is really not enough  information here.